# How can I make a for loop in Spark Web Framework and the Velocity Template Framework?

Tags: java, loops, frameworks, velocity, spark-java

Here is my Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create some students
        Student students[] = new Student[4];

        students[0] = new Student("Abe");
        students[1] = new Student("Bill");
        students[2] = new Student("Chris");
        students[3] = new Student("Darrel");

        staticFileLocation("/public");

        String layout = "templates/layout.vtl";

        get("/", (request, response) -> {
            HashMap model = new HashMap();
            model.put("template", "templates/home.vtl" );
            return new ModelAndView(model, layout);
        }, new VelocityTemplateEngine());

        get("/view_students", (request, response) -> {
            HashMap model = new HashMap();

            model.put("students", students );
            // model.put("student", new Student() );

            return new ModelAndView(model, "templates/view_students_layout.vtl");
        }, new VelocityTemplateEngine());

    }
}
```

And here is the view_students_layout.vtl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello Friend!</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

    <h1>Students</h1>

    <ul>

      #foreach( $Student in $students )
        <li>${Student.name}</li>
      #end

    </ul>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run spark I get the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello Friend!</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

    <h1>Students</h1>

    <ul>

              <li>${Student.name}</li>
              <li>${Student.name}</li>
              <li>${Student.name}</li>
              <li>${Student.name}</li>

    </ul>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing or misunderstanding? Am I sending the array in the wrong way to the framework?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Student class must have a `public String getName()` method, or a `public String get(String key)` method. You're either trying to access directly the `name` field, or you forgot to make its accessor public.

If you want to directly expose public fields to the template, then you'll need the 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT version (development version). See http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html section **Pluggable Introspection**.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried looking at the same guide that you linked and couldnt find anything about my problem.